# magento 1.4.1 maintenance script

Tags: magento

I found the following maintenance script:
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/article/log-cache-maintenance-script/

Is it still needed for magento 1.4.1 or does the shell/log.php do the trick?

The script empty also the tables:
catalogindex_aggregation, catalogindex_aggregation_tag', catalogindex_aggregation_to_tag'
Is it ok? Is this script safe to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintenance script by Crucial Webhost does not only clear the log tables in the database, but also the var directory in the file system. As far as I know there's no feature as of Magento 1.7 that will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

`shell/log.php clean` will [do the same thing](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.4/shell/log.php) the Crucialwebhost script does.  So yes I would say it is not needed anymore.  You can also specify automatic log cleaning within the Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Log Cleaning.

Comment: catalogindex_aggregation, catalogindex_aggregation_tag', catalogindex_aggregation_to_tag don't show in the link you gave. That's why I asked if the script and shell/log.php clean are doing the same thing.